# How to preview a html file in another tab/window without saving it on disk?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, browser, preview

Hy,

In my application I store a string as content of a html file.

How can I preview this content (assuming that it's modified from original content) in browser but not having to save it to disk locally.

And the preview to be in another tab or window.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the content to a Session variable and make a dummy page and load to content from the Session variable in the Page Load event.

Where your temp content are created

```
Session["TempPage"] = Content;
```

And then have a ShowTempPage.aspx that is empty with code behind Page Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Session["TempPage"]);
}
```

Something like that could work..

Update:
To open the temp page in a new window create a link like this on the main page:

```
<a href="http://localhost/ShowTempPage.aspx" target="_blank">View temp Page</a>
```

Comment: yep.. I've tried this, it opens in the same window/tab.. i need it to open in another window/tab

Comment: as i said.. the html content might be modified from the user interface, that means when user press some button I read the html comntent with some client script (javascript) and return it to a string in code behind.  So, how can I use <a/> because it has no methods?

Comment: I'm starting to get a bit confused what you actually want to do here.. You don't mention JavaScript and client side scripting at all in your question. Please edit your question and define exactly how your solution look like and what you want to accomplish. That will make it easier for anyone answering your question instead of small updates in comments here and there :)

Answer (score 1):

[Creating "in memory" Files](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/902d4b30-ae56-4de4-9b11-4e859ff52591)
[How Make A Text File In Memory And Write Something On It And Open NotePad In Client And Open That File In It?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621471/how-make-a-text-file-in-memory-and-write-something-on-it-and-open-notepad-in-clie)

Answer (score 1):

Create an HTTP Handler, and in the implementation of [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) serve the HTML content from memory. Use the correct `target` attribute on the link to force new tab/window on the client.

(That's based on the `asp.net` tag on the question: you're writing a web site. If this is a local application (WinForms or WPF) then you can embed a browser control and set its [`NavigateToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx) method to the HTML text.)

Comment: The linked `IHttpHandler` page on MSDN has links to Walkthroughs (ie. structured samples) and overviews. Start with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would use an iframe and a piece of javascript. Use javascript and document.write to fill the iframe window.

Comment: I'm not using windows forms, asp.net web application in c#

Comment: Ah, sorry I read it to quick... in that case I would use an iframe and a piece of javascript. Use javascript and document.write to fill the iframe window.

Answer (score 1):

Is the question mostly just how to open a new window? This depends on what prompts the action. If it's a hyperlink, just add `target="_blank"`. If not or you want more control over the window then use javascript.

Showing content without saving it to disk is the very nature of server-side code, you can't have a web site without doing this.

Response.Write(myString)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Javascript/JQuery solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Open Custom HTML Page Without Saving</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.preview-site').on('click', function(){
    window.open('javascript:document.write("'+ $('.workflow').val() +'")', 'Opened Page', 'width=660, height=440');
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="preview-site" title="Preview your workflow" href="javascript:void(0)">Preview your workflow</a><br/>

  <textarea class="workflow"><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello world!</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```